# Add bootstrap tag into ul tag

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tags

I want to add tag as NEW in `ul` tag just like in gmail when new message comes and hides automatically after few second.
UPDATED:
[image]
Is it possible to be done with bootstrap?

Comment: Not sure what you want to do, but you could use something like jQuery's [`.toggle("highlight")`](https://api.jqueryui.com/highlight-effect/) or a bootstrap [add on that displays toasts](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/)

Comment: Do you mean a notification system?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use "li" tag to add new element in ul (list). You can do it via jquery append / prepend method.

Example;

```
<ul id="messages">
<li>And ol message<li>
</ul>

<script>
$('#messages').prepend('<li>New message</li>');
</script>
```